# Local Git repository does not exist after successful clone from cygwin bash

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

When I clone to the directory (that does not exists) referred to via absolute path, git does not complain about anything, report 0 exit code but the directory is **not** created. Git complies the directory **do** exist when I retry:

```
user@host /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/zandev/shunit2.git /tmp/shunit01
Cloning into '/tmp/shunit01'...
remote: Counting objects: 1219, done.
emote: Total 1219 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1219
Receiving objects: 100% (1219/1219), 308.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (657/657), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

user@host /tmp
$ echo $?
0

user@host /tmp
$ ls /tmp/shunit01
ls: cannot access /tmp/shunit01: No such file or directory

user@host /tmp
$ git clone https://github.com/zandev/shunit2.git /tmp/shunit01
fatal: destination path '/tmp/shunit01' already exists and is not an empty directory.

user@host /tmp
$ echo $?
128
```

The directories does not seem to exist when checked from cygwin, powershell or Windows UI. I have not seen any indication of an error of any kind. The same problem can be observed for Admin account.

I can clone the repo correctly when non-absolute path is used (`shunit02`, or even `../tmp/shunit02`).

Using:

- Windows 7 Enterprise Ver 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1
- git 2.5.1.windows.1
- cygwin 2.3.1-1

**EDIT:**

The `/tmp` directory is seen as `C:\cygwin64\tmp` by windows. I used `/tmp` as an example, the same happens in `/cygdrive/c` in fact.

**EDIT 2:**

I am using Git for Windows. The clone works when using widows path for target like: `git clone https://github.com/zandev/shunit2.git 'C:\cygwin64\tmp\shunit4'`

Comment: Can you please tell us the permissions on the tmp folder? Also, what is the absolute location of the tmp folder (i.e. what is the output of  `cygpath -w -p /tmp`   OR if you do   `cd /tmp && explorer . `   which folder opens up?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by *Git for Windows* [not accepting cygwin paths](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/568), therefore `/a/b/c` got translated to `c:\a\b\c`. In fact, that is where the repositories are cloned and it explain why subsequent clone attempts fail. The directory in fact exists, though the real destination is unexpected.

### What will work?

- Use bash shipped with *Git for Windows* and their path conventions,
- Use cygwin git that accept cygwin paths (reportedly, there might be other problems),
- Use native windows paths: `git clone https://github.com/zandev/shunit2.git 'C:\cygwin64\tmp\shunit4'`,
- Use relative target names as it seems to work without problems.

Comment: Why does not these guys globalized the folder structure throughout all the flavors of OS exists!! really daunting for developer :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you try renaming the existing `/tmp` and re-creating it **in the cygwin installation folder** as described in http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#tmpfiles :

#### Suggestion 1

> Q: After I installed cygwin, and I started it    it gives the
>   following messages:       bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please
>   create!       bash: /etc/profile: Invalid argument        bash: /.bash_profile:
>   Invalid argument
>
> A: You need to first create the directory /tmp.  A**ssuming     your
>   cygwin root directory is called C:/cygwin, that means     you should
>   first create the directory C:/cygwin/tmp**.

#### Suggestion 2

It seems you are using Git Bash for Windows' git executable in Cygwin. It might be worth trying to use the git executable that Cygwin itself provides.

Comment: I do not observe any of the symptoms from the question. However, I have recreated the `/tmp` and the issue persists.

Comment: thanks, is it worth trying to use the git executable that Cygwin provides instead of the msysgit one to see if the problem is reproducible?