# Git bash.exe error ":warning could not find /tmp, please create!"

Tags: git, git-bash

Can someone please help me how to resolve this? I get this error when I open git bash. 
I tired hard to look up online but no luck so far.
I have Win8.1. Please help.

Comment: It's literally right there in the error message

Comment: I am totally new to Git where exactly do I have to create this tmp directory? I read some other comments that even after creating this directory the issue wasn't resolved.

Comment: If you haven't even tried it yet why do you ask? "/tmp"  is a full path

Comment: `mkdir /tmp` from within the `git-bash` shell environment might be what you need.

Comment: tmp directory is already there in c:\users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\. Where do I have to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply uncompress the archive [`PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want.

Then open `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.4-64-bit\git-bash.exe`: you won't see that error message.

Comment: Thank you VonC. This has stopped giving me that error. I am very much thankful to you. I don't understand what was the issue.

Comment: @ForTesting what version of git were you using before? And where you trying to use it in a cygwin environment (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34276621/6309)?

Comment: I was using Git-2.6.3-64-bit. I had some issues using EGit to merge my code so I started using Git bash. Updated the merge tool to use as perforce merge in .gitconfig.